# Dialog with OK/Cancel behavior in C#/WPF with data binding

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

In my App class, I have a Collection of objects, like this:
(the Collection is in the App class because I need to have access to it application-wide in different windows, etc.)

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get; set; }

    public App()
    {
        Persons = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Tim", Age = 20 });
        Persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Sarah", Age = 30 });
    }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

On the main window of the application, there is a `ComboBox` binding to the Persons Collection:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Application.Current}, Path=Persons}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Now I want to create a dialog, in which the user is able to add/remove/edit persons with the well known OK/Cancel button behavior. Can this be down easily? One important thing is that the items in the `ComboBox` must not be affected by the changes the user is making before pressing OK.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: I think I should point out that I don't want to edit a specific person in the dialog, but the whole list of persons.

Answer (score 3):

Add and remove are simple enough since it will only happen when you click OK.

For editing, you more options:

1. Make `Person` implement `IClonable`, pass in a cloned copy of the `Person` you are editing to be bound on the edit form, then switch out the appropriate `Person` in your `Persons` collection when you're done.  This makes the edit form less complicated and more WPFey.
2. Don't use binding on your edit form, just do a manual synch between the controls and the `Person` passed in when you're done.  Least WPFey.
3. A combination of 1 and 2 - the edit form has properties that mirror the properties of `Person` and are bound to its controls, then you synch the `Person` with the form's properties when you're done.